# How to get Mechanize to auto-convert body to UTF8?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, mechanize

I found some solutions using `post_connect_hook` and `pre_connect_hook`, but it seems like they don't work. I'm using the latest Mechanize version (2.1). There are no `[:response]` fields in the new version, and I don't know where to get them in the new version.

- https://gist.github.com/search?q=pre_connect_hooks
- https://gist.github.com/search?q=post_connect_hooks

Is it possible to make Mechanize return a UTF8 encoded version, instead of having to convert it manually using `iconv`?

Comment: iconv will be deprecated in ruby 1.9 builds. have a look at String.froce_encoding

Comment: Mechanize changes encoding back to the ASCII-8BIT, even if I everywhere set to encoding, force_encoding, encode'ed string in encoding mechanize hook. Everything the same. I guess I need to hack on headers and html's meta's charset.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. At the bottom I've already explained with a new `encode` method.

Comment: Your gist links are no longer valid.

Comment: @zhon fixed. Checkout if you can help with more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Mechanize 2.0, arguments of `pre_connect_hooks()` and `post_connect_hooks()` were changed.

See the [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html) documentation:

> pre_connect_hooks()
>
> A list of hooks to call before retrieving a response. Hooks are called with the agent, the URI, the response, and the response body.

> post_connect_hooks()
>
> A list of hooks to call after retrieving a response. Hooks are called with the agent, the URI, the response, and the response body.

Now you can't change the internal response-body value because an argument is not array. So, the next best way is to replace an internal parser with your own:

```
class MyParser
  def self.parse(thing, url = nil, encoding = nil, options = Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::DEFAULT_HTML, &block)
    # insert your conversion code here. For example:
    # thing = NKF.nkf("-wm0X", thing).sub(/Shift_JIS/,"utf-8") # you need to rewrite content charset if it exists.
    Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(thing, url, encoding, options, &block)
  end
end

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.html_parser = MyParser
page = agent.get('http://somewhere.com/')
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that works pretty well:

```
class HtmlParser
  def self.parse(body, url, encoding)
    body.encode!('UTF-8', encoding, invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
    Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(body, url, 'UTF-8')
  end
end

Mechanize.new.tap do |web|
  web.html_parser = HtmlParser
end
```

No issues were found yet.

Answer (score 1):

In your script, just enter:  `page.encoding = 'utf-8'`

However, depending on your scenario, you may alternatively need to enter the reverse (the encoding of the website Mechanize is working with) instead. For that, open Firefox, open the website you want Mechanize to work with, select Tools in the menubar, and then open Page Info. Determine what the page is encoded in from there.

Using that info, you would instead enter what the page is encoded in (such as `page.encoding = 'windows-1252'`).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
class Mechanize
    alias_method :original_get, :get
    def get *args
        doc = original_get *args
        doc.encoding = 'utf-8'
        doc
    end
end
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Still getting '<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<title>\xCD\xE5\xE4'

Comment: I agree, it's better to write a get method that calls @agent.get and does the conversion. Your question seemed to ask for a monkey patch though.

Comment: Monkeypatch is too ugly, this feature should be inside mechanize. https://gist.github.com/480277 - does more or less what I need, but I can't do the same using the `content_encoding_hooks`, because inside the mechanize in the Page class there are some code that converts encoding to ASCII-8BIT and then no possible to return it to the WINDOWS-1251 and convert to UTF-8. So if you can write code using the `content_encoding_hooks`, please update your record and I will give you +50, and this question will be marked as answered. Thank you.