# How to search in page body and force an encoding conversion

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, mechanize

I have pretty simple code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

URL = 'http://yandex.ru'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(URL)

# page.encoding => UTF-8
# page.body.encoding => ASCII-8BIT

page.body.include?("Карты")
```

And on the last line of that code Ruby returned an error:

```
in `include?': incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
```

Solutions from "[How to get Mechanize to auto-convert body to UTF8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864493/how-to-get-mechanize-to-auto-convert-body-to-utf8)" don't help. What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `force_encoding` method like this:

```
agent.page.body.force_encoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: Yes. That works. But are the way for make it automatically through configuration of Mechanize?

Comment: I think so you can just find the best answer with opening issue in github :) https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/issues/489